# SDL Rendering transparent rectangle using SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, rendering, alpha, sdl-2

I could find nothing about rendering transparent rectangles in SDL2 documentaries. I want to render SDL_Rect as transparent texture/surface/anything used as "fog of war". Maybe you know any way to make surface or texture from SDL_Rect or just render it transparent. I don't want new texture in game files because player could just delete file and he would not have that fog of war.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I managed to do it by myself and if anyone else will have same question thats the answer:

```
SDL_Surface* Fog = NULL;
SDL_Texture* gFog = NULL;

Fog = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
if (Fog == NULL)std::cout << SDL_GetError();

gFog = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, Fog);
if (gFog == NULL)std::cout<<SDL_GetError();

SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(gFog, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(gFog, 150);
```